# How to say Alpha Male and Alpha Female in Spanish?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos, género

How does one say

- [Alpha Male](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Alpha%20Male) (dominant, *macho* man)
- [Alpha Female](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Alpha%20Female) (dominant, *femenina* woman)

in Spanish?

Answer (score 2):

We do use the expression "macho alfa" in Spanish (the greek letter alpha translates to alfa in Spanish.)

I haven't heard much, if at all, the expression "hembra alfa" but that would be the translation, and we can see in the ngram viewer that it's somewhat used.

[image: NGrams macho alfa - hembra alfa. Hay pocas hembras alfa]

Other alternative would be to use "[dominante](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=macho%20dominante%2C%20hembra%20dominante&year_start=1975&year_end=2019&corpus=32&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmacho%20dominante%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chembra%20dominante%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmacho%20dominante%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chembra%20dominante%3B%2Cc0)" instead of "alfa", although there we tend to use "hombre" and "mujer" instead of "macho" and "hembra".

The ngram graph for ["hombre dominante" and "mujer dominante"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hombre%20dominante%2C%20mujer%20dominante&year_start=1975&year_end=2019&corpus=32&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chombre%20dominante%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmujer%20dominante%3B%2Cc0) is priceless.

[image: hombre dominante - mujer dominante - domina la mujer en el pasado]